# tomcat: startup.sh doesn't deploy war file

Tags: tomcat

I put the war file under /webapps directory, and as I start tomcat by running `./startup.sh`, the war file is not deployed, but tomcat is successfully started as the tomcat start page can be seen.

Why doesn't the war file get deployed?

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/company/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/lib/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/company/apache-tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /packages/encap/java-1.6.0_24
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/lib/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/var/company/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

This is the from server.xml.

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>

  </Host>
```

Answer (score 2):

At a wild guess, is deployOnStartup not set to true?

Showing some configuration and/or console output might help.

Comment: I didn't change any configuration file and the console output is updated.

Comment: Actually, the deploying works for the first time, and after that, it doesn't work any more.

Comment: Can you show your Host element from the server.xml? I'm pretty sure the behavior you describe is the behavior of Tomcat (at least 6.0) with the default configuration.

Comment: @Olaf I have added the host element from server.xml

Comment: +Cacheing Can you clarify "first time, and after that?" Are you trying to redeploy by copying a new war file into webapps while the server is stopped? That won't work if the old war is still expanded.